# Javascript parameter is returned as both value and undefined

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to pass an object to a function to plot a graph according to the values it contains. However, when I pass the object to the function javascript reads it as both an object and undefined:

```
$(plot({pv : '1000', d : '20', n : '10'}));

highcharts.js:45 {pv: "1000", d: "20", n: "10"}
highcharts.js:47 object
highcharts.js:45 undefined
highcharts.js:47 undefined
```

Then when I try to access `data['pv']` or `data.pv` I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'pv' of undefined
    at calculate (highcharts.js:55)
```

But if a access a global variable it runs smoothly:

```
var obj = {pv : '1000', d : '20', n : '10'};
```

I'm dipping my toes into Javascript at the moment so I'm sure there's something extremely basic I'm not understanding about the language. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the rest of my ugly code for reference:

```
$(function () {
    $(plot({pv : '1000', d : '20', n : '10'}));
});

// Global variables
var pv = 0;
var r = 0.015;
var n = 0;
var d = 0;
var x = new Array();
var y = new Array();
var v = new Array();
var before = new Array();
var obj = {pv : '1000', d : '20', n : '10'};
    // Plot button
function plot(data) {
    // if (isValid()) {
        console.log(data);
        calculateBefore(data);
        calculate(data);
        plotValues();
    // }
};

function calculate(data) {
    console.log(data);
    // pv = Number($('#pv').val());
    console.log(typeof(data));


// obj = data['pv']; 
console.log(obj);
pv = Number(data['pv']); // Error appears on this line
// r = Number($('#r').val()) / 100;
r = 0.015;
// d = Number($('#d').val());
d = Number(data['d']);
var xmin = 0;
// var xmax = Number($('#n').val()) * 4;
var xmax = Number(data['n']) * 4;
var i = 0;
v = [];
for (xt = xmin; xt <= xmax; xt++) {
    x[i] = xt;
    y[i] = calculateY(pv, r, xt);
    v[i] = [x[i], y[i]];
    i++;
  }
n = i - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that data itself is undefined, so if you tried to `console.log(data)` you would get undefined. The data that is referenced in your function is a parameter so you cannot access it outside of your function scope.

As an aside, you should try to stay away from using global variables and `var` in general. You can use `const` for variables that are not going to change and `let` for variables that you expect will change.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to trigger the function with the variable as an argument, not the object, I mean:

`$(plot(obj));`
not
`$(plot({pv : '1000', d : '20', n : '10'}));`